# How easy to indentify memory like ROM or EEPROM Flash Memory Areas of a Chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, eeprom, rom, core

Can anyone tell me would the memory circuit areas (**ROM**, **EEPROM**, **SDRAM**, **Flash** **Memory**) of the layers of a die belonging to a **MCU** and **SoC** IC's be relatively easy to identify compared to identify circuit core sections of the IC ?

Where on the die would you find the above circuit areas (**ROM**, **EEPROM**, **SDRAM**, **Flash** **Memory**) ? Would they be generally be located on the top layer or could these areas be just about anywhere on the die ?

Comment: http://zeptobars.ru/en/read/how-to-open-microchip-asic-what-inside : the memory areas are the regular gridlike structures.

Comment: @pjc50 Nice link :-)

Answer (score 4):

On a chip ALL LAYERS are used for ALL structures. All layers are needed to make the components (transistors, diodes, resistors, capacitors) and connect them. The difference with memories can be seen because memories require very regular structures.

[image: LM1117 low-dropout linear regulator]
<sub>(source: [zeptobars.ru](http://s.zeptobars.ru/LM1117.jpg))</sub>

Note how the above photo of the LM1117 (from Zeptobars, [CC Attribution 3.0 Unported Licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) as noted on [Contacts page](https://zeptobars.com/en/contacts)) — it's a voltage regulator, it has no memories — is "messy" at the bottom. The only regular structure is at the top which is probably the output transistor.

Note how the MT4C1024 DRAM below (also from Zeptobars) has very regular structures (RAM) but not at the edges, these are the drivers for the memory.

[image: Micron MT4C1024 — 1 mebibit (220 bit) dynamic ram]

What you see in the photos (thanks to the [link to a Zeptobars article](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/how-to-open-microchip-asic-what-inside) provided in [pjc50's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199154/how-easy-to-indentify-memory-like-rom-or-eeprom-flash-memory-areas-of-a-chip#comment416106_199154)) are the connections between the components. The components themselves are under these connections. They are usually too small to see even on these micro photos.